# fadein images proloaded with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

image preloading code snippet :

```
myimages=new Array()
function preloadimages(){
   for (i=0;i<preloadimages.arguments.length;i++){
      myimages[i]=new Image()
      myimages[i].src=preloadimages.arguments[i]
    }
}

preloadimages("img/1.jpg","img/2.jpg","img/3.jpg","img/4.jpg")
```

jquery code to display preloaded images:

```
$(".vrpl_slider_img").fadeIn(40000).html(myimages[i]);
```

I used image preloading so that the first image in my slider does not take time to show up, but it does with a blank space instead and all the consequent images show up without showing any blank space. But I don't know how to fadeIn the images during display.

the following code

```
$(".vrpl_slider_img").fadeIn(40000).html(myimages[i]).fadeIn('slow');
```

shows an error in console:

```
$(".vrpl_slider_img").fadeIn(40000).html(myimages[i]).fadeIn is not a function
```

I want a slider the one in http://www.cisco.com/

1) what should be the steps so that no blank space shows up at the very first time the slider begins? Putting code inside `$(document).ready(..` or not does nothing.

2) how to achieve the fadeIn effect?

3) In http://www.cisco.com/, for each image, the text on the image seems to be highlighted a bit after the rest part of the image. How to achieve that?

**EDIT**:

after the image preloading snippet, the next segment follows:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++){

$(".vrpl_slider_img").fadeIn(40000).html(myimages[i]);



if(i==n-1){

i=0;
}
    }
```

that is all about the part of the slideshow I am interested to discuss here.

Comment: jQuery is not included. try `$(function() {alert('jQuery working')});` if there's no alert, there's no jQeury.

Comment: shows alert. If jQuery were not there, how could the jQuery code lines in the question work?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but your question states that you are getting `fadeIn is not a function` error, so something is obviously wrong with jQuery since fadeIn should be a function. Either you are doing something before jQuery is loaded, or jQuery is'nt loaded at all. Did you try my function and did it alert, if so jQuery is ok. It's just a quick test to see if jQuery is included correctly to check for the most obvious reasons for fadeIn not being a function. On the other hand you can just as easily put those images in a div positioned off screen, and they will be preloaded aswell.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to be calling `.html()` on an img tag.  You want to be setting the `.src` attribute on the `img` tag to point it to a new image.  Assuming that `.vrpl_slider_img` is initially not visible, you would use this:

```
preloadimages("img/1.jpg","img/2.jpg","img/3.jpg","img/4.jpg")

// then some time later after the preload images have loaded
$(".vrpl_slider_img").attr("src", "img/1.jpg").fadeIn(40000);
```

You do not need to use the preload images at all once they've been loaded.  The point of the preload images it to cause the images to get loaded into the browser cache so they are available locally (rather than over the internet) and will thus be loaded immediately when requested in the future.  So, you just use the `.src` attribute with the normal image path and, because the image is in the browser cache, it will load immediately.

Comment: then how will the image preloading  take place?

Comment: then in which case should the image-preloading be used?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - you still call the `preloadImages()` function.  You just don't use the preloadImages directly after calling it - you just set the image `.src`.  Use the code like I showed.

Comment: why to call the preloadImages() function then? I just can't get the idea

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - Did you read the last paragraph in my answer?  It tells you what the point of the `preloadImages()` function is.

Comment: I see. But when I refresh the page, a blank space shows up. what to do?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - I don't know what the problem is on refresh.  You'd have to show us your actual working code.  It's not a preload problem because the images are already in the browser cache on a refresh - it's likely something else.

Comment: $(".vrpl_slider_img").attr("src", "img/1.jpg").fadeIn(40000); - how to use 'myimages[i]' instead of "img/1.jpg" ?.Just replacing does not show any image.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - you don't use `myimages[i]` to set the `.src` tag on another image tag.  HTML just doesn't work that way.

Comment: so , for n images, I have to write the attribute setting code line in a for loop ... for(i=1; i<=n; i++){$(".vrpl_slider_img").attr("src", "img/"+i+".jpg").fadeIn(40000); Am I right? Or any better way?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - you'd have to include more of your code and explain more of what you're trying to do for us to know the best way to do it.  The code you have there does not look like it would do anything useful as it is just looping through a big loop and setting the same images very quickly to different `.src` values which won't accomplish anything useful.

Comment: added an 'EDIT'. Please notice.